# How to send message to a chatroom using xmpppy?

Tags: python, xmpp, chatroom, xmpppy

I've successfully sent message to individual user. How can I send message to a room? I'm trying the following code:

```
cl.send(xmpp.Message('99999_myroom@chat.hipchat.com', 'test message', typ='groupchat'))
```

Also, I'm sending this message without sending presence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send a message to a room, you must join the room first.  From [XEP-0045, section 7.2.2](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html#enter-muc):

```
<presence to='99999_myroom@chat.hipchat.com/my_nickname'>
  <x xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/muc'/>
</presence>
```

Then your message should work.

Comment: Thanks. For anyone having the same problem first define the namespace `NS_MUC = 'http://jabber.org/protocol/muc'`, then define presence, `presence = xmpp.Presence(to=ROOM_JID)`, and finally, set the x tag like this `presence.setTag('x', namespace=NS_MUC).setTagData('password', 'PASSWORD')`. Now, you can send presence with your client `client.send(presence)`

Answer (score 2):

Here is the basic implementation for sending a message to a room chat. You need to send your presence to the group, and also set the message type to 'groupchat'.

Tested with Openfire server

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys,time,xmpp

def sendMessageToGroup(server, user, password, room, message):

    jid = xmpp.protocol.JID(user)
    user = jid.getNode()
    client = xmpp.Client(server)
    connection = client.connect(secure=False)
    if not connection:
        print 'connection failed'
        sys.exit(1)

    auth = client.auth(user, password)
    if not auth:
        print 'authentication failed'
        sys.exit(1)

    # Join a room by sending your presence to the room
    client.send(xmpp.Presence(to="%s/%s" % (room, user)))

    msgObj = xmpp.protocol.Message(room, message)
    #Set message type to 'groupchat' for conference messages
    msgObj.setType('groupchat')

    client.send(msgObj)

    # some older servers will not send the message if you disconnect immediately after sending
    time.sleep(1)   

    client.disconnect()
```

Comment: Be aware to use the correct _user_ and _room_ IDs. User-JID might look like `username@domain.tld` and room-JID might look like `room@conference.domain.tld`.

Answer (score 0):

Some older XMPP servers require an initial presence notification. Try this before your `cl.send`:

```
cl.SendInitPresence(requestRoster=0)
```

See also http://xmpppy.sourceforge.net/examples/xsend.py